# Is it possible to change config spec but only update partially

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have a huge clearcase snapshot view including about 10 VOBs, and it takes more than an hour to update the whole view.

Now I'm trying to change the config spec a bit to select several file elements with another timestamp. But by default, changing config spec will trigger a whole view update which is really slow. What I need is just to update the file elements with the updated timestamp.

I read through the official document about `cleartool setcs`, and also googled some time but it seems impossible. So Here's my question. **Is it possible to change config spec of a snapshot view but only update partially?**

Actually I also got a workaround here.

I opened the snapshot view in `ClearCase Explorer`, changed the config spec, clicked OK to update, and then cancelled after the update started. After that, I just updated those selected file elements.

The workaround was OK just for readonly. But I could not checkout/checkin because of the abort of update. The following error popped up when trying to checkout. So I had to update the whole view again.

> *An update appears to have been aborted or errors were encountered during an update. An update must be performed on the element to enable
>   a checkout.*

Hence, here's another question. **Is there any "brute" way to avoid the error for the workaround, since I know the config spec change won't affect other elements?**

Besides, any other idea or workaround to solve my problem is absolutely welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to use a dynamic view (at least to try different config specs and check that the right versions are selected, before using that config spec on a snapshot view if you must.

Another approach is to use 10 snapshot views, one per Vob, because you can update them in parallel, making the all process faster, and starting some of the checkouts faster